# javafx pane white artifact when rendering text and rounded rect

Tags: java, button, javafx

Javafx creating white artifacts appear at the site of the rounding rect
I want to create this rect with rounded corners, but for some reason when I try to add a button white artifacts appear when rendering
code:

```java
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(320, 160);
        rect.setArcWidth(25);
        rect.setArcHeight(25);
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Button button = new Button("Button1"); 
        Text text = new Text("SomeText");
        text.setFont(font);
        stackPane.getChildren().add(text);
        stackPane.getChildren().add(asGuest);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(rect, stroke);
        pane.getChildren().add(stackPane);
        primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem; it seems that the `Pane` creates it; adding the following line seems to solve it:

```java
// given the imports:
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;

// line:
pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
```

(as per the comment from Slaw, this can be simplified to `pane.setBackground(null)`)

Comment: Note this can be simplified to `pane.setBackground(null)`.